# How web browser handles AJAX post and HTML redirection on a same page?

Tags: html, ajax, redirect

I want to redirect the user to a new page by using the  HTML tag and post some data to another page; so I have this piece of code

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script source="jquery.js"></script>
        <meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="0; url=http://current.domain/some_page.html">
    </head>
    <body>
        <script>
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "http://current.domain/another_page.html",
                data: data,
                success: success,
                dataType: dataType
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I am testing the code in my localhost, so the process is very fast and I won't notice anything. But I'm wondering when does the browser handle the AJAX post:

- A - Before the redirection: The AJAX post must be done first, then comes the redirection.
- B - At the same time with the redirection: The browser will redirect and still post the data in the background.
- C - After the redirection: The AJAX post will be done after the browser has successfully redirected to the new page.

Can anybody give me an explanation for this please? Personally I prefer the B and C cases, in which the user doesn't have to wait if the AJAX post takes long time.

Comment: meta refresh is deprecated and breaks the back button. you shouldn't use that. also, your script may not even run at all in some browsers. You should do a plain form post, and have the javascript just submit that form and use the http redirect headers to move it to some_page.html, and not use jquery for the post.

Comment: I agree - drop the `meta` tag

Comment: I have checked this page http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/meta and found nothing says that the <meta> tag with 'refresh' attribute is deprecated. Besides, I don't use a plain HTML form but AJAX because I want to post the data automatically.

Answer (score 0):

This is unlikely to work reliably. You ask whether the AJAX operation will happen before, during or after the redirection: the answer is it *might* happen before, depending on the browser and possibly its version as well. You've set up what is known as a *race condition* where it is difficult to know what will happen first: will the browser notice you want it to redirect first, or that you want to run an AJAX operation immediately?

It would be more reliable to use PHP on this page to redirect using the `Location` header, and then for the target page to carry out the AJAX operation. You might also consider whether you need an AJAX operation at all: if you are running a server-side script when generating the target page, you could do the AJAX work at the same time, which would save you an HTTP call.

Incidentally, when you run `$.ajax()`, you should probably wrap it in a DOM-ready handler, especially if you intend to pass values from form elements.